# Why isn't the cppconn folder in /usr/include?

Tags: 12.04, mysql, c++

I am new to C++.

I am trying to make a MySQL connection. I found that it requires mysql-connector. I installed [boost-dev-all [image: Install boost-dev-all]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/boost-dev-all). I have put my `mysql-connector` in local directory `~/bin`. I have successfully installed it.

But when I try to make mysql connection, I get an error:

```
fatal: cppcon: directory missing
```

On digging around, I understoodd `cppconn` folder has been missing from `/usr/include`. Should I copy `cppconn` folder to `/usr/include`?

```
sudo cp /bin/mysql-connector /usr/include
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have not installed the [libmysqlcppconn-dev [image: Install libmysqlcppconn-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libmysqlcppconn-dev) package, which provides the `cppconn` directory in `/usr/include`. You can install this package with:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I solved it by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn7v5 libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

This installed all required header files in */usr/include/cppconn*. After that I was able to compile my program.